# How to catch a given user ID to display different Activity in Login?

Tags: java, android

with this Login form, an admin with (ID: 001) should get a 'AdminActivity' whereas every other userID should get a 'UserActivity', and this is the code. It's not returning the adminID for some reason. Thank you

```
btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {

                UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();   

                String id = inputId.getText().toString();
                String pswd = inputPassword.getText().toString();

                JSONObject json = userFunction.loginUser(id, pswd);             

                try {
                    if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                        loginErrorMsg.setText("");

                        String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS); 

                        if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){

                            DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());

                            JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");                          

                            if(id == "001"){
                                // Launch Admin Activity
                                Intent tab1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AdminActivity.class);                     
                                    // Close all views before launching requestActivity
                                tab1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                startActivity(tab1);
                            }

                            // Clear all previous data in database
                            userFunction.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());

                            db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_ID), 
                                       json_user.getString(KEY_NAME), 
                                       json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL),                                     
                                       json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));                            

                                // Launch User Activity
                            Intent tab = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UserActivity.class);                       
                                // Close all views before launching requestActivity
                            tab.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            startActivity(tab);


                        }else{

                            loginErrorMsg.setText("Incorrect username/password");
                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: It looks like you have the start of some promising code. What happens when you try to use that code? Does it throw an exception? If so, please post the logcat. If not, what behavior do you observe?

Comment: actually no. it doesn't throw any error..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    if("001".equals(id)){
                            // Launch Admin Activity
                            Intent tab1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AdminActivity.class);                     
                                // Close all views before launching requestActivity
                            tab1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            startActivity(tab1);
                            return;
                        }
```

Comment: got it working! after I moved the block of code belowthe db.addUser. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can't compare Strings in Java using `==`
Try something like this: 
`if(id.equals("001"))`